# React: Name not coming through onChange(), e.target.name is undefined on DatePicker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, datepicker

I'm using a building a MERN Stack application (`"react": "^16.14.0"`) that has a form using DatePicker (`"react-datepicker": "^4.2.1"`) to set a date range. Currently, the value for the date is being selected, but the name is coming through undefined. This is throwing a TypeError and crashing the application when a date is selected.  How do I set the e.target.name to startDate and endDate?

TyperError

```
react-dom.development.js:327 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') 
  at onChange (index.js:55)
```

formData

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
  startDate: '',
  endDate: '',
})

const {
  startDate,
  endDate,
} = formData
```

DatePicker

```
<DatePicker
  isClearable
  filterDate={(d) => {return new Date() > d}}
  placeholderText="Select Start Date"
  dateFormat="MMMM yyyy"
  selected={startDate}
  selectsStart
  startDate={startDate}
  endDate={endDate}
  onChange={(date) => onChange({ name: startDate, value: date })}
/>
```

onChange Function

```
const onChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e) 
  setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
}
```

Console.log()

```
name: undefined
value: Tue Aug 03 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why that happens is that you onChange is not receiving any event, thus the e.target is undefined. if you take a look here:

```
// Add the name explicitly as a string, cause you're trying to update a key by its name
onChange={(date) => onChange({ name: "startDate", value: date })}
```

The onChange is receiving and object with the name and value keys. so the onChange function should be like this:

```
const onChange = (item) => {
  console.log(item) 
  // should print something like { name: "startDate", value: "the date object" }
  setFormData({ ...formData, [item.name]: item.value })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally we get field name using `event.target.name`.
But while we are using any component library that time it's depend on library how library developer gave way to get field name. so you have to check library  document.

Surprise you have one more way.
Just need to pass field name in onChange function
`<DatePicker value={dateValue} onChange={(date) => onChange(name,date)} />`

`onChange=(name, date)=>{ console.log(name,date) }`